# Problem with sending data to back-end with Thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have one object with users which contains two fields: `username` and `role`. This object is in an arraylist, so when I send data to the front-end (HTML with Thymeleaf), I display them in a table with rows.

Everything so far is OK and is working.

After this, from this table I have one button for each row and user, where I want, on click, to send to the back-end a new object containing the current username added in this new object field
`th:field="${usersRole.username}"`. But it is null every time.

Where I am mistaken?

This is HTML page:

```html
  <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Username</th>
         <th>Role</th>
         <th>Available Roles</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
         <form th:action="@{/admin/change}"
               method="post"
               th:object="${usersRole}">
 
 
                 <td th:field="${usersRole.username}" th:text="${user.username}">
 
             <td th:text="${user.userRole}">
 
             <td>
                 <select th:field="${usersRole.role}">
                     <option value="ROLE">Role</option>
                     <option value="USER">User</option>
                 </select>
             </td>
             <button type="submit">Change</button>
         </form>
 
     </tr>
 
     </tbody> 
</table>
```

This is "users" in html

```
public class UserForAdminDto {
private String username;
private String userRole;
```

And "usersRole"

```
public class RoleChangeDto {
private String username;
private String role;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `<td>` tag doesn't work with `<form>`
Not pretty sure but I did a test

In https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It works perfectly

But when I changed the code to

```
<tr>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <td type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John">John</td><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <td type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe">Doe</td><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form> 
</tr>
```

it didn't work anymore

Solution: insert `<input>` tags inside your `<td>` tags like this
[link to image (my code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4kdx.png)

```
  <form th:object="${registerRequest}" th:action="@{/register}" method="post">
            <p class="text-center text-danger" th:text="${error}"></p>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="inputUsername" class="form-label">Tài khoản</label>
                <input th:field="*{username}" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                <small th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}" class="form-text text-danger"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="inputFullName" class="form-label">Tên đầy đủ</label>
                <input th:field="*{fullName}" class="form-control" id="inputFullName" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                <small th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('fullName')}" th:errors="*{fullName}" class="form-text text-danger"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="form-label">Email</label>
                <input th:field="*{email}" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                <small th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}" class="form-text text-danger"></small>
            </div>
```

Comment: It is working for roles, but not for usernames

Comment: yeah it works for roles cause' your role value in "<select>" - a part of form but your username in a "<td>" tag